# Why are `std::env::{Args, ArgsOs}` not `Send` and `Sync`

Tags: multithreading, rust, environment-variables

I am very curious why `std::env::{Args, ArgsOs}` are not `Send` and `Sync` because they actually allocate the memory for those CLI arguments, so IMO, they are basically equivalent to `Vec<OsString>` or `Vec<String>`, and I see no reason for a `Vec<String>` being `!Send` and `!Sync`

> More context on their allocation:
>
> Unsafely, they don't need to allocate given that the memory has already been allcoated in libc, which is exactly what the [`argv`](https://crates.io/crates/argv) crate did.

Comment: Is this [issue: Send and Sync impls of ::env types depend on implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48004) the answer?

Comment: The reasoning is probably that these properties can't be guaranteed for all platforms, so they're not provided for any platforms -- otherwise code that compiles on one platform would break on another.

Comment: @cdhowie, interested in expanding your comment and making it an answer? I am curious about the details

Comment: From this [comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/48005#issuecomment-362947861), at the time they made these 2 types `!Send` `!Sync`, it seems that these types are really not `Send` and `Sync` because they have raw pointers, but things seem to be changed as the inner `Args` type is basically `vec::IntoIter<OsString>` now

Comment: You can open an issue if there isn't any reason to not make them `Send + Sync` anymore.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman issue filed: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/118700